# WPF airspace issue and WinForms IDesignHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms-interop

I'm trying to migrate portions of an app to WPF. One of the near-impossible parts is an `IDesignerHost` (i.e., a Windows Forms Designer). So for that, I want to use a WPF window with a `WindowsFormsHost` inside.

I've observed two issues in the default behavior:

- Windows Forms has strange colors when `WindowChrome` is used (see https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/issues/141 and https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF/issues/60)
- any WPF control will clip if it partially overlays WinForms controls (obviously, this is the airspace issue)

Wrapping the `WindowsFormsHost` in `AirspaceDecorator` with the mode set to `Redirect`, both of those disappear. Controls look right, and I can place WPF controls on top as well.

However! That setting seems to affect something related to… drag & drop, maybe?

If I use the `IDesignerHost`'s toolbox to create a new control, I can use the mouse to click and drag in order to set its size, then let go to have the new control be created.

But if I take an *existing* control, I cannot move it *at all*. I get an "unavailable" cursor, as though it's trying to initiate a drag & drop operation (with itself as the target). This does not happen if I remove the `AirspaceDecorator`; moving controls does work, then.

(Incidentally, the behavior seems to be the same for `AirspaceMode="Clip"`: I can show WPF controls on top, but I cannot move WinForms controls inside the `IDesignerHost`.)

TL;DR: I need a way to host an `IDesignerHost` inside a WPF window, and with the current `AirspaceMode="Redirect"` approach, *almost* everything seems to work except actually moving controls in the designer around.

**Edit:**

From [Seeking a Winforms System.ComponentModel.Design Design Surface BeginDrag/EndDrag Event Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223524/seeking-a-winforms-system-componentmodel-design-design-surface-begindrag-enddrag), I gathered that `BehaviorService` is involved in the actual movement of controls. If I make a `BeginDrag` event handler and set a breakpoint on that, then move a control,

1. the event does fire,
2. bizarrely, after resuming execution, the control *has* moved to its new position. (But if I *don't* set the breakpoint, I can't get the control to move, even if I let go of the mouse.)

So presumably, it's not that the designer doesn't want to perform the drag operation; it's that *something else also* wants to.

Comment: Winforms and WPF have to totally different approach to data binding and design method... is it possible to consider to re-write the winform into a WPF user control?

Comment: Yes, the poor view-model separation is one of the reasons I want to migrate away from WinForms. ;-)

I don't believe rewriting `IDesignerHost` in WPF is feasible. Even if it were, it's only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Well designer in WPF is your xaml, no names for UI elements, Binding support in xaml are just a few to name. I can't think of anything that would be difficult in WinForms that can't be done in WPF. Maybe you are approaching it from WinForms view, which is to create controls yourself, WPF you have base controls and then use behaviours, attached properties etc. Styles alone will decrease amount of work needed. Maybe you should ask more specific question about how to convert what you have into WPF?